# Funny colouring of Hexdump

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I recently posted [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461814/how-to-produce-unformatted-output-from-man?noredirect=true) on apple.stackexchange which contains a hex dump, like this:

```
00000210: 616e 7369 6f6e 0a20 2020 2020 2020 5f08  ansion.       _.
```

Different to here (on Meta Stackexchange), the hexdump in apple.stackexchange was syntax coloured - some hex values displayed in red and some in green.

Is there a deeper meaning in these colours? I wonder according to which rule the colours are chosen here.

Comment: Looks like the numbers containing only decimal digits, are coloured differently from those containing the letters a-f.

Comment: @S.L.Barthsupportsmodstrike : Sounds reasonable! I wonder what highlighter is actually used here. If you post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'll wait a bit to see if a more informed answer comes by. So far, I only have a single observation. I don't know why the highlighting there is different from the highlighting here.

Comment: @S.L.Barth it's different because of different default language between the sites, or more likely the tags there having associated highlight language.

Comment: In this specific case, it's more likely different since the linked question contains many lines, and this one only one

Comment: I see no hexdump anywhere on that page. Did you link to a wrong question?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you might be using adblock which hide it. There is hex dump, this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/So61o.png.

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I’m not using any adblocks or anything of that sort. Now I see that the page is *completely* different. It seems that I get automatically redirected to what appears as the duplicate question target in your screenshot. Is this because I don’t have an account on Ask Different? If so, this is extremely confusing behaviour.

Comment: And, sure enough, now that I’ve “joined this community”, the link works. So, yes, this must be intended behaviour, but I can’t describe it any other way than *idiotic*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek huh! Forgot about it, and fixed it by adding flag telling SE to not redirect, link should now work for everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is being highlighted as [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Which makes sense, I guess, YAML allows numbers and strings without string separators, and often begins lines with a string, then a colon.

You can find this out by inspecting the HTML, which reveals:

```
<code class="hljs language-yaml">
   <span class="hljs-attr">00000210:</span> 
   <span class="hljs-string">616e</span> 
   <span class="hljs-number">7369 </span>
   <span class="hljs-string">6f6e</span>
etc...
```

And you can of course disable this by specifying lang-none

Comment: Weird, according to the [tag page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/zsh/info) of the tag used in the question, the default language is `lang-shell`. (And `lang-bash` for the other tag)

Comment: As I understood it, the syntax highlighter is not smart enough to prefer these if multiple are listed in the tags and just goes to lang-default, but I could be wrong, can't seem to find that documented.

Comment: According to [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work): "By default, Stack Exchange uses the tags on a question to determine the language you are using. If there's more than one tag that has a highlighting language specified, it lets highlight.js infer what's the best language to use", so it should be either shell or bash.

Comment: @Shadow That's not really clear, I read that as "let highlight.js infer == lang-default", but I see how you could interpret it differently

Comment: @Shadow given that yaml was used, Erik's interpretation is correct - so the choice is not between tag-associated languages (which would be the more sensible thing to do), but based on the general detection method.

Comment: @Marijn yeah, wonder how the faq answer can be made more clear then.

Comment: @ErikA’s interpretation is correct. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354793/improving-syntax-highlighting-language-auto-detection for a request to fix this.